# Nextjs - React withAuth HOC not rendering component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am using a HOC in REACT + NextJS for rendering a component only when user is signed-in.

## Issue

I works when user is NOT logged in, but it won't render the component after logging in.

> HOC

```js
import React from 'react';
import redirect from './redirect';

export const withAuth = (Component) => {
  return class AuthComponent extends React.Component {
    static async getInitialProps(ctx, { currentUser }) {
      if (!currentUser) {
        return redirect(ctx, "/auth/signin");
      }
      return {}
    }
    // if user is logged in
    render() {
      return (
        <Component {...this.props} /> // not rendering the page 
      )
    }
  }
}
```

> Used as in Next Pages :

```js
export default withAuth(ProjectShow);
```

## Error

[image]

Comment: And you aren't getting any error? It just shows a blank page?

Comment: Updated the error.

Comment: seems like it's saying that ProjectShow is being rendered, but that it is not returning anything? What happens if you remove withAuth() from ProjectShow? Does that work as expected?